# Obtener Ubicación Javascript (Navegador Android)

Tags: javascript, html

Obtengo la ubicacion en cualquier navegador web de PC y todo sale bien con el siguiente codigo:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(obtener_ubicacion);
```

function obtener_ubicacion (ubicacion) 
{
  $('.longitud').val(ubicacion.coords.longitude);
  $('.latitud').val(ubicacion.coords.latitude);
}

Pero al intentar obtener la ubicación desde cualquier navegador web de ANDROID con GPS activado y permisos de Ubicacion me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual seria la solucion para obtener la UBICACION desde un navegador web ANDROID.

Comment: Hola, leiste lo que te manda el link?, ahi dice que para pruebas (localhost) funciona pero cuando este publicado (IP Remota) debes si o si usar https. Estas usando HTTPS?

Comment: Ya estoy en producción con ip publica, pero con HTTP.

Comment: Intenta que usar https, te mandara un mensaje de error el navegador, pero tu aplicacion funcionará, me avisas

Comment: Intenta hacer esto con **Cordova,** puedes programar aplicaciones para IOS y Android en HTML5, CSS y JS. Para la geolocalización, prueba a crearte una [API de Google Maps](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?refresh=1&pli=1) y generar un mapa con tu ubicación.